# Create User with Avatar in Sails.js fails when Avatar is an image/png

Tags: forms, api, upload, sails.js

I generated & implemented a new api called `User` using the `sails generate`
 command. When I try to uploading an svg or jpg image, it works perfectly, the file is uploaded and the user is created in the DB. However, when I try using a png file instead, the saving to the DB fails! Although the png file would be uploaded as expected, the user wouldn't be saved. When debugging, the Object Param is empty except for the field "company".

**Generating the api**

```
$ sails generate api user
```

**User Controller** (api/controller/UserController.js)

```
'create': function (req, res, next) {
        var params = req.params.all();
        var format = req.param('format');
        delete params['format'];

        req.file('avatar').upload({
            maxBytes: 10000000,
            dirname: sails.config.appPath + '/assets/images/avatar/'
        }, function (err, uploadedFiles) {
            if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
            console.log(uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!');
            console.log(uploadedFiles);
            params["avatar"] = uploadedFiles[0].fd;

            User.create(params, function userCreated(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    req.session.flash = {
                        err: err
                    }
                    return res.redirect("/user/new");
                }

                if (format == 'json') {
                    res.json(user);
                } else {
                    res.redirect('user/show/' + user.id);
                }

            });

        });
    },
```

my views/user/new.ejs:

```
<form id="register-form" action="/user/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="company" class="validate">
    <input name="avatar" type="file">
    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
    <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="first_name" class="validate">
    <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="last_name" class="validate">
    <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" name="phone"
    <input id="icon_mail" type="email" name="email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
    <input name="type" value="Auftraggeber" type="radio" id="auftraggeber" checked/>
    <input name="type" value="Auftragnehmer" type="radio" id="auftragnehmer" disabled/>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" pattern=".{6,}" title="6 characters minimum"
    <input id="confirmation" type="password" class="validate">
    <input type="hidden" value="<%= _csrf %>">
    <input type="checkbox" id="accept"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="not_robot"/>
    <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

**User model** (api/models/User.js)

```
module.exports = {

    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        avatar: {
            type: "String"
        },
        first_name: {
            type: "String",
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            type: "String",
            required: true
        },
        type: {
            type: "String",
            enum: ['Auftraggeber', 'Auftragnehmer']
        },
        phone: {
            type: "String",
            unique: true
        },
        email: {
            type: "String",
            email: true,
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: "String",
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            type: "String",
            required: true
        },
        toJSON: function () {
            var obj = this.toObject();
            delete obj.password;
            return obj;
        }

    }

};
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I searched over 2 weeks and found this:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2326

You don't have to install skipper and require('skipper') => Sails comes automatically with skipper! Also don't use it as a policy, it won't work ( didn't for me).

**What you have to pay attention to for a *multipart/form-data* form with text input and file input, where you want to upload the image/file and also save the data (the file name) in the DB at once is: the order of your input fields in your html form matters! Place the text input fields on the top and the file input field at the bottom of your html form.**

Answer (score 1):

you can use skipper package to handle different types of images

run this command in terminal

```
npm install skipper --save
```

at the top of your controller `app.use(require('skipper')());`

now can use this package

```
req.file('image').upload({
  // ...any other options here...
}, ...);
```

Comment: I could test it: error: A hook (`controllers`) failed to load!
error: ReferenceError: app is not defined. this is not the way how sails work with app.use() => instead of that I added this to my config/policies.js:   '*' : require('skipper')(),  but it doesn't work at all. its loading and loading, and the the Object Param is empty again. Have you ever worked with sails.js? did the uploading part + saving data in DB worked for you? thank you